# How to setup Spring Cloud Zuul server as proxy server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I tried to use Spring Cloud Zuul server as proxy server, but when I access my default context it does not redirect to url destination.

For example:

```
@EnableZuulServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class ZuulServerApp {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ZuulServerApp.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Start Spring application
        SpringApplication.run(ZuulServerApp.class, args);

        LOGGER.warn("Startup completed and listening");
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
###################
### Spring Boot ###
###################
server.port=8765
spring.main.show-banner=false

zuul.routes.resource.path=/**
zuul.routes.resource.url=http://www.uol.com.br
zuul.routes.resource.stripPrefix=true
```

Is there any configuration missing?

```
http://localhost:8765/ does not redirect to http://www.uol.com.br
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `@EnableZuulProxy` to your `ZuulServerApp`:

> You can also run a Zuul server without the proxying, or switch on
>   parts of the proxying platform selectively, if you use
>   `@EnableZuulServer` (instead of `@EnableZuulProxy`). Any beans that you
>   add to the application of type `ZuulFilter` will be installed
>   automatically, as they are with `@EnableZuulProxy`, but without any of
>   the proxy filters being added automatically.
>
> In this case the routes into the Zuul server are still specified by
>   configuring `zuul.routes.*`, **but there is no service discovery and no
>   proxying, so the "serviceId" and "url" settings are ignored**.